# How to get a KeyHandler to register a key combination?

Tags: c#, key, combinations

I'm working on a school project, and I've run into an issue. I am working on a program that will kill other processes that are active when a combination of keys is pressed. Using the internet, and with a help of a friend Ive came up with this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private KeyHandler ghk;

    public object WindowForm { get; private set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ghk = new KeyHandler(Keys.End, this);
        ghk.Register();
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);
    private void HandleHotkey()
    {
        //Ovde ide kod
        GetActiveProcessFileName();

    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)
            HandleHotkey();
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    void GetActiveProcessFileName()
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
        p.Kill();
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Procesni asistent", "Proces " + p.ProcessName + " je ubijen.", ToolTipIcon.Info);
    }
```

Rest of the code is about the tray icon (minimizing, strip menu...)
I am only able to set one key, and thats really impractical, because if that keys is to ever be used while the program is running in the background, the app in focus will be killed. Does anyone know of a way to implement a combination of keys instead of just one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the library you use (why do we have guess?) to see how to specify modifier keys.  A completely blind guess would be Keys.End | Keys.Shift | Keys.Alt to specify Alt + Shift + End.

Comment: @HansPassant
Ive tried that. It doesn't work.
&& doesn't work either, nor does +

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442805/vb-net-key-combination) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803761/how-do-you-detect-simultaneous-keypresses-such-as-ctrl-t-in-vb-net) are for VB.Net but it should be easy to convert them to C#